# Error al crear un archivo en C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando crear un programa en C que, a partir de un fichero pasado por parámetro, copie el contenido del fichero y modifique su extensión tal que en la primera posición aparezca ".DST". Por ejemplo, si ejecuto desde la terminal:

```
prog1 test.txt
```

Se tiene que crear un fichero que se llame test.DST.txt y contenga el mismo contenido. Hasta ahora he podido crear el segundo fichero con la extensión correctamente y el contenido, el problema es el nombre del fichero que por alguna razón sale con carácteres extraños. Aquí la ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo actual:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE * fp1, * fp2;
    char ch;
    char filename[80];
    char filename2[80];
    int cnt = 0;
    int data = 0;
    // Comprueba que solo haya dos parámetros al ejecutar el archivo
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("El número de parámetros no corresponde con el deseado.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]); //copia el valor del parametro a la variable filename
    printf("%s", filename);
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r"); // Abre el archivo con ese nombre para leerlo
    char * token = strtok(filename2, " . "); //guarda en una variable la primera posición donde se encuentra "."
    strcat(token, ".DST."); //añade la extensión ".DST."
    char * pointer;
    strtok_r(filename, ".", & pointer); //guarda en una variable la primera posición donde se encuentra "."
    strcat(token, pointer); //concatena pointer con token
    fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w"); //Abre un archivo con nombre "filename2" para escribir en el

    // Comprueba que archivo fp1 existe
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("\n%s File can not be opened : \n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    //Mueve el puntero hacia el final
    /*fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_CUR);*/
    //Recoge la posición del puntero
    /*cnt = ftell(fp1);*/
    // Recoge char uno a uno y lo imprime en el fp2

    while ((data = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        fputc(data, fp2);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //Cierra los dos archivos
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde asignas un valor a filename2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un detalle que no estás teniendo en cuenta es que `strtok` **modifica** la cadena original, reemplazando el caracter separador por un caracter nulo. Una posible implementación de `strtok`:

```
char* strtok(char* ptr, char sep)
{
    static char* next = NULL;
    
    if( !ptr )
       ptr = next;

    char* start = ptr;

    while( *ptr && *ptr != sep)
    {
        ++ptr;
    }

    *ptr = '\0';
    next = ++ptr;

    return start;
}
```

Así que esta opción no te sirve, ya que estás perdiendo información que puede ser de tu interés.

Lo que tienes que hacer es componer un string nuevo, siendo éste último el resultado de la composición que esperas crear.

A modo de utilidad, necesitamos una función que nos indique la posición de un caracter dentro de una cadena:

```
int strpos(char *haystack, char const* needle)
{
   char *ptr = strstr(haystack, needle);
   if(ptr)
      return ptr - haystack;
   return -1;
}
```

Con esta utilidad, crear la composición es *casi* trivial:

```
char filename[50];
char filename2[50] = { 0 };

strcpy(filename, argv[1]);

int pos = strpos(filename, ".");
memcpy(filename2, filename, pos+1);
strcat(filename2, "DST");
strcat(filename2, filename + pos);
```

Es importante inicializar `filename2` para que las operaciones de `strcat` funcionen correctamente.

Comment: Le has dado justo en el clavo!! Muchas gracias compañero :D